# PHP with SOAP - Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I'm starting to learn PHP with SOAP, but during my initial test to see how it works I run into this error

```
Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL:
Couldn't load from 'http://localhost/M07_ACT5/servidor.php?wsdl' : 
Extra content at the end of the document in C:\xampp\htdocs\M07_ACT5\cliente.php:4 
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\M07_ACT5\cliente.php(4):
SoapClient->__construct('http://localhos...') 
#1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\M07_ACT5\cliente.php on line 4
```

It throws it on the soapclient constructor line, but what is the *extra content*?

I made sure that my php.ini file allows the use of SOAP.

```
Client.php

<?php

require_once("lib/nusoap.php");
$client = new soapclient('http://localhost/M07_ACT5/servidor.php?wsdl'); <---- HERE
$result = $client->holaMundo();
echo $result;

?>
```

This is my server.php file for this test. I checked if the name space is right but it's in the correct folder.

```
<?php

require_once("lib/nusoap.php");
$namespace = "http://localhost/M07_ACT5/servidor.php";
$server = new soap_server();
$server->configureWSDL("MiServicioWeb", $namespace);
$server->schemaTargetNamespace = $namespace;
$server->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';

function holaMundo(){
    return "Hola, mundo!!!";
    }

    
    $server->register(
        'holaMundo',
        array(),
        array('return'=>'xsd:string'),
        $namespace,
        false,
        'rpc',
        'encoded',
        'Método HolaMundo '
        );
        
        $server->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));
?>
```

[image: This is my folder structure , maybe it has something to do with it.]

Comment: If you open this in the browser `http://localhost/M07_ACT5/servidor.php?wsdl` does it return a properly formatted WSDL? Are there extra characters at the end of it? Without seeing the WSDL it's hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: @Bogdan it shows: **This page contains the following errors:
error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.**

Comment: If you can't see a proper WSDL, then the service is broken in some way. Perhaps a bad library? Have you looked up the error? https://www.google.com/search?q=%22This+page+contains+the+following+errors%22+and+%22Extra+content+at+the+end+of+the+document%22+AND+%22Below+is+a+rendering+of+the+page+up+to+the+first+error%22+AND+php+AND+WSDL